# Unconfirmed Transaction >22 hrs

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

I realise that this might be a duplicate however I have not actually seen a sufficient answer to the question aside from 'wait'.

I submitted a transaction yesterday from a blockchain wallet to a Justcoin wallet.
It was quite a small transaction (test transaction as this is my first) 
Below is the information I have from blockchain:

**Fees**    0.0001 BTC

**Estimated BTC Transacted**    0.00000001 BTC

**Size**    258 (bytes)

**Received Time**   2014-08-20 14:27:54

**Estimated Confirmation Time**     Within 6 Blocks (Medium Priority)

The transaction ID is:
https://blockchain.info/tx/5ea993b10e772f1e31218a02b843adc18a0e4d1176b3127f0170c5c08bb0361c

The problem I have with this is, it's stopping any other transactions I want to make.
Anytime I try to move more substantial figures I receive the error: 
"No Free Outputs To Spend - Some funds are pending confirmation and cannot be spent yet"

Does anyone have any idea why it's taking so long (I'm guessing because of it's size?) and if there is anything I can do to expedite the transaction.

Answer (score 3):

One of your transaction outputs is below "dust" limit. Most of nodes do not relay and mine such transactions. However, there are miners who accept such transactions.

There are two possibilities:

1. just wait (may be a day or two) for such miner
2. try to double-spend your transaction with another one

Please read https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=232979.0 for more info